# Alterar idioma no app e permanecer alterado

Tags: java, android, locale

Tenho um app e gostaria que o próprio usuário alterasse caso queira

Seguindo esse [link](http://pt.androids.help/q29361) até deu certo, porém se eu limpar o cache do celular (acho que é isso) ou seja limpar todas as telas abertas e tentar abrir novamente, ele não permanece com o idioma escolhido.

Como faria para que quando ele voltasse para o app reconhecer o idioma alterado. Eu pensei em salvar o idioma no banco de dados e recuperar, porém depois que eu limpo o cache dá a mensagem de esperando pelo debugger

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que eu inseri esse código:

```
try {
            database = new Database(this);
            conn = database.getWritableDatabase();
            repositorioLocale =  new RepositoriosLocales(conn);
            int lingua = repositorioLocale.getIntLocale();
            if(lingua > 0){
                idioma = repositorioLocale.getRecLocale();
                setLocale(idioma);


           }else{

                repositorioLocale.inserirLocale(getResources());

            }

        }catch (SQLException ex){

        }
```

Comment: no aguardo, pra vocês isso é fácil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocar uma base de dados é uma opção, mas acho que não se justifica, se é apenas para guardar o idioma. 
Pesquisa sobre SharedPreferences, que é outra forma de guardar dados e funciona através de {key, value}, é bastante simples de usar.

Comment: mesmo assim, limpar o cache ele não permanece com o idioma

Comment: consegui.. acho que era isso mesmo. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés da base de dados, acho que poderias usar o SharedPreferences.

Ele usa a mesma lógica, e é mais recomendado para esses efeitos!

Comment: mesmo assim, limpar o cache ele não permanece com o idioma